# Microsoft Identity platform (AAD v2.0) protected Azure AD B2C API - expired access token works until restart

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an API protected with Microsoft Identity platform (AAD v2.0), but although I have configured the access token to have a 5 minute lifetime in the B2C login user flow I can successfully use the access token after it has expired.

I have it setup like this:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            },
            options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // Create policy to check for the scope 'user_access'
                options.AddPolicy("UserAccess",
                    policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ScopesRequirement("user_access")));
            });
```

The controller is protected with the attribute: `[Authorize]`

I call the controller GET method using Postman and the header `Authorization: Bearer <access token>`

I get the access token using (parameters omitted):

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
```

And I get the access token using:

```
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

The `expires_in` field is correctly showing 5 minutes. The login policy is the same as used for the API setup.

If I restart the API before the access token has expired I can continue using it. If I restart the API after it has expired it stops working after restart. If I don't restart it just keeps working.

This is in debug and localhost.

I would have expected the access token to be rejected by the API once it has expired. What have I missed?

Comment: I think this may be affected by the cache, what if you refresh it?

Comment: That seems possible, but I don't know where that cache would be. I haven't setup any caching in the API.

Comment: Further testing confirms that the access token eventually expires even without a restart, but it takes a lot longer than the expected 5 minutes. Around 10+ minutes. Since it takes effect immediately on restart it seems reasonable to guess that it might be some sort of caching, but I'm not aware of any caching so I am a bit confused.

Comment: Thanks and please refer this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview